# Proving Limit Property

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it possible to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)^a=\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)\right)^a$ (most probably using the $(\epsilon,\delta)$-definition of limits), **for all (not necessarily integral) *a***, provided that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)$ exists? (If so, how?) I have seen multiple proofs, but all of them assume $a$ to be an integer.

Comment: Yes, $n$ always denotes an integer

Comment: That's what I thought, but I've seen many abuses of `when n is a real number` before

Comment: I've changed it to be `a`; is there a better alternative? @Andrew

Comment: Also I'm bad with tags; can anyone help? what other [tag:tags] should I make?

Comment: Assuming $f(x)^a$ is defined everywhere near $c$, this is a consequence of the fact that the function $g(x)=x^a$ is continuous at every point in its domain. All you need is that if $f$ has limit $L$ as $x\to c$ and $g$ is continuous at $L$, then $\lim_{x\to c}g(f(x)) = g(\lim_{x\to a} f(x))$.

Comment: Can you format this into an answer? Also, how can I prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(f(x))=g(\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x))$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yet $g(x)=x^{-1}$ is not continuous... therefore i think the equation just doesnt hold

Comment: @NumberBasher $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is continuous *at every point in its domain*. Which is what I said. Therfore I think you are not paying sufficient attention. The formula holds when all terms make sense. Note that the same caveat is present in the formula $\lim(f+g) = \lim f + \lim g$.

Comment: @NumberBasher By the way, one usually says "$f(x)$ is continuous" to mean it is continuous at every point in its domain (with suitable one-sided continuity for endpoint). You mean that $x^{-1}$ is not continuous **everywhere** (because it is not defined everywhere). "$f$ is continuous everywhere" and "$f$ is continuous" do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @Arturo Magidin is a great approach. To show the fact on which it relies

> If $\lim_{x \to c} f (x) = L$ and $g (y)$ is continuous at $y = L$, then $\lim_{x \to c} g (f (x)) = g (L)$

is simple. Assume the hypotheses of the propostion. Take any $\varepsilon > 0$. We show that there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for each $x'$ satisfying $0 < |x' - x| < \delta$, that $|g (f (x')) - g (L)| < \varepsilon$.

By continuity of $g$ at $y = L$, we have, for any $\varepsilon_1 > 0$, that there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $|y' - L| < \delta_1 \implies |g (y') - g (L)| < \varepsilon_1$.

Since $\lim_{x \to c} f (x) = L$, for any $\varepsilon_2 > 0$, that there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that $0 < |x' - x| < \delta_2 \implies |f (x') - L| < \varepsilon_2$.

Choosing $\varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon_2 = \delta_1$ completes the proof.

Comment: can we set epsilons? don't we set deltas?

Comment: I showed that for *every* $\varepsilon_1 > 0$ that there exists some $\delta_1 > 0$ satisfying property $X$, and that for *every* $\varepsilon_2 > 0$ there exists some $\delta_2 > 0$ satisfying property $Y$. Now we just pick a particular $\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2$ (in this case, $\varepsilon$ and the $\delta_1$ guaranteed by the first statement, respectively), which guarantees a $\delta_2$ by the second statement, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume here that $f$ takes real numbers as input but might output complex numbers. I will then at the end distinguish this from the case where the output needs to be real.

Denote by $D$ the domain of definition of $f$ and suppose that $L := \lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists in $\Bbb R$.

Note two things. If $L>0$, then letting $\epsilon = L/2$, we have a neighborhood $V$ of $c$ such that $-L/2 < f(x) - L < L/2$ in $D\cap V$. So that $f(x) > L/2 > 0$ in $D \cap V$. Similarly, if $L <0$, setting $\epsilon =-L/2$ gives us a neighborhood $V$ of $c$ such that $f(x) < L/2 < 0$ in $D \cap V$.

Consequently, if $a = 0$ and $L \neq 0$, then the claim holds.

If $a =0$ and $L =0$, then the claim doesn't even make sense because the RHS literally reads $0^0$.

Now if $a > 0$ and $L=0$, then the RHS is $0$, and the LHS is:

$$\lim_{x \to c} e^{a \log(f(x))}$$

Note that if on each neighborhood $W$ of $c$, $f$ attains the value $0$ in $D \cap W$, then the LHS limit doesn't exist because $\log(0)$ is undefined. So, there must be a neighborhood $W$ of $c$ such that $f$ never vanishes in $D\cap W$. But then, one has for $A < 0$, $\log A = \ln |A| + i\pi$, and for $A>0$, $\log A = \ln A$, so that:

- whenever $f(x) >0$, $e^{a \log(f(x)) } = e^{a\ln f(x)}$.
- whenever $f(x) < 0$, $|e^{a\log(f(x))} | = e^{a\ln|f(x)|}$

and by the continuity of exponential and $\ln$, both of these go to $0$ as $x \to c$ if $a>0$. Hence, this case holds.

If $a<0$ and $L=0$, then the claim doesn't hold because the RHS reads a negative power of $0$ which doesn't exist.

Now if $a \neq 0$ and $L > 0$, then the claim holds. Indeed, as at the beginning there's a neighborhood $V$ of $c$ such that $f(x) > 0$ in $D \cap V$, and so in $D \cap V$, $\log(f(x)) = \ln(f(x))$. And the continuity of exponential and $\ln$ give us the LHS limit as $e^{a \ln L}$ which is $L^a$, same as the RHS.

If $a\neq 0$ and $L<0$, then we have a neighborhood $V$ of $c$ such that $f(x) <0$ on $D \cap V$. And then:

$$e^{a \log(f(x)) } = e^{a (\ln|f(x)| + i\pi)}$$

and by continuity of exponential and $\ln$, he limit of this is $$e^{a \ln|L| + i\pi} = e^{a \log L} =L^a$$

and so the claim holds as well.

Therefore, assuming that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists,

1. If $L \neq 0$, then the claim holds for all $a \in \mathbb R$.
2. If $L = 0$, then the claim holds if and only if $a > 0$.

Now if we are seeking only seeking limits in $\Bbb R$, then when $L<0$, we have an issue, but for $L\ge 0$ there's nothing to worry about.

Assume that $L < 0$. Then $L^a = e^{a \log L} = |L|^a e^{i \pi a}$, so that $L^a \in \Bbb R \iff a \in \Bbb Z$.

Therefore, in the $\mathbb R$ case,

1. If $L > 0$, then the assertion is true for all $a \in \mathbb R$.
2. If $L = 0$, then the claim holds if and only if $a > 0$.
3. If $L < 0$, then the claim holds if and only if $a \in \mathbb Z$.

I did not treat the case where we allow infinite limits, but in my opinion the very writing of

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x)^a = \left( \lim_{x \to x} f(x) \right)^a$$

without context implicitly assumes no infinite limits.